# Why do I get this 500 status error when trying to access my python backend built into NextJS in production mode?

Tags: python, flask, next.js, backend

I am using the template from the following GitHub repo: https://github.com/vercel/examples/tree/main/python/nextjs-flask to setup a publicly accessible api. My next.config.js looks as follows:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  rewrites: async () => {
    return [
      {
        source: "/api/:path*",
        destination:
          process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"
            ? "http://122.10.10.1:3328/api/:path*"
            : "/api/",
      },
    ];
  },
  async headers() {
    return [
      {
        source: "/:path*",
        headers: [
          { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", value: "true" },
          {
            key: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
            value: "http://localhost:3000, https://api.name.tech",
          },
          {
            key: "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
            value: "GET,DELETE,PATCH,POST,PUT,OPTIONS",
          },
          {
            key: "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
            value:
              "X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version",
          },
        ],
      },
    ];
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

I have altered the sensitive information in the config, do not worry.

My problem is that I can access the api and I get a status 200 in the response when trying this out on localhost:3000. I run the code

```
fetch("/api/analyse")
```

and it works out as you would expect in the sense that "success" is returned — my api function looks like the one below:

```
@app.route("/api/analyse")
def analyse():
    return "success"
```

When going to the domain api.name.tech and making the same fetch call (to /api/analyse) I get an error with status 500. Why is it that the code does not work in production?

First of all, I took out all the meat in the function to make sure that there is no python syntax error or something along those lines.

Secondly, I experimented with allowing different methods by using

```
methods=["POST", "GET"]
```

when defining the router. The reason I did this was that I got a 405 error. I then fixed that error by editing the next.config.js.

I have boiled it down to a couple of causes which in my view are likely:

1. the next.config.js is setup wrong.
2. the Flask API is not being hosted correctly.

But I do not know how to fix the last bit of the problem.

Comment: Just an error 500? No content in the response?

Comment: @AKX I am not great at using API:s, is there something specific I should look for in the response? It looks like this: Response

body: ReadableStream {locked: false, cancel: function, getReader: function, pipeTo: function, pipeThrough: function, …}

bodyUsed: false

headers: Headers {append: function, delete: function, get: function, getSetCookie: function, has: function, …}

ok: false

redirected: false

status: 500

statusText: ""

type: "basic"

url: "https://api.name.tech/api/analyse"

Comment: You should probably read the body stream to see what the error message is, if any.